# Why does the player freeze when trying to go back from the second scene to the first one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, phaser-framework

I have two scenes. I switch between them when encountering a trigger. But when trying to go back to the first scene of the second scene, the player freezes and does not move anymore. I've tried cleaning variables, but it doesn't seem to work... There are no errors in the console. How can I fix this?

Further explanation:

I want to switch scenes freely. Load the first one when it collides with a trigger in the second scene, or load the first one when it collides with a trigger in the second scene. But after loading the second scene, in the event of a collision with a trigger, the player simply freezes and does not move.

This is client-side code.

```
class FirstScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'first' });
  }

  init(data) {
    console.log('Updating FirstScene');
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image('player', 'assets/player.png');
    this.load.image('otherPlayer', 'assets/player.png');
    this.load.image('mouse', 'assets/mouse.png');
  }

  create() {
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    let self = this;
    socket.on('currentPlayers', players => {
      Object.keys(players).forEach(playerId => {
        if (playerId === this.socket.id) {
          addPlayer(this, players[playerId]);
        } else {
          addOtherPlayers(this, players[playerId]);
        }
      });
    });

    socket.on('newPlayer', playerInfo => {
      addOtherPlayers(this, playerInfo);
    });

    socket.on('disconnectPlayer', playerId => {
      otherPlayers[playerId].destroy();
      delete otherPlayers[playerId];
    });

    socket.on('playerMoved', playerInfo => {
      otherPlayers[playerInfo.playerId].x = playerInfo.x;
      otherPlayers[playerInfo.playerId].y = playerInfo.y;
    });

    socket.on('mouseSpawned', mouseInfo => {
      const mouse = this.add.sprite(mouseInfo.x, mouseInfo.y, 'mouse').setDisplaySize(50, 50);
      mouse.id = mouseInfo.id;
      mice[mouse.id] = mouse;
    });

    addPlayer(this, { x: 400, y: 500 }); // temp location
    const trigger = this.add.rectangle(400, -12, 100, 100, 0xffffff).setDisplaySize(50, 50);
    // Define the collider after the player has been created
    this.physics.add.existing(trigger);
    trigger.body.setImmovable(true);
    this.physics.add.collider(player, trigger, () => {
      this.scene.switch('second');   
    });
  }

  update() {
    if(player) {
      if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(-160);
      } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(160);
      } else {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
      }
      if (cursors.up.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityY(-160);
      } else if (cursors.down.isDown) {
         player.setVelocityY(160);
      } else {
        player.setVelocityY(0);
      }
      socket.emit('playerMovement', { x: player.x, y: player.y });
    }
  }
}

class SecondScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'second' });
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image('player', 'assets/player.png');
    this.load.image('otherPlayer', 'assets/player.png');
    this.load.image('mouse', 'assets/mouse.png');
    this.load.image('background', 'assets/background.png');
  }

  create() {
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    let self = this;
    this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background').setOrigin(0, 0);

    socket.on('currentPlayers', players => {
      Object.keys(players).forEach(playerId => {
        if (playerId === this.socket.id) {
          addPlayer(this, players[playerId]);
        } else {
          addOtherPlayers(this, players[playerId]);
        }
      });
    });

    socket.on('newPlayer', playerInfo => {
      addOtherPlayers(this, playerInfo);
    });

    socket.on('disconnectPlayer', playerId => {
      otherPlayers[playerId].destroy();
      delete otherPlayers[playerId];
    });

    socket.on('playerMoved', playerInfo => {
      otherPlayers[playerInfo.playerId].x = playerInfo.x;
      otherPlayers[playerInfo.playerId].y = playerInfo.y;
    });

    socket.on('mouseSpawned', mouseInfo => {
      const mouse = this.add.sprite(mouseInfo.x, mouseInfo.y, 'mouse').setDisplaySize(50, 50);
      mouse.id = mouseInfo.id;
      mice[mouse.id] = mouse;
    });

    addPlayer(this, { x: 400, y: 500 }); // temp location

    const trigger = this.add.rectangle(400, -12, 100, 100, 0xffffff).setDisplaySize(50, 50);

    // Define the collider after the player has been created
    this.physics.add.existing(trigger);
    trigger.body.setImmovable(true);
    this.physics.add.collider(player, trigger, () => {
      this.scene.switch('first');
    });
  }

  update() {
    if(player) {
      if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(-160);
      } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(160);
      } else {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
      }
      if (cursors.up.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityY(-160);
      } else if (cursors.down.isDown) {
         player.setVelocityY(160);
      } else {
        player.setVelocityY(0);
      }

      socket.emit('playerMovement', { x: player.x, y: player.y });
    }
  }
}

const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 0 }
    }
  },
  scene: [FirstScene, SecondScene]
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
const socket = io();
let cursors;
let otherPlayers = {};
let mice = {};
let player;

function addPlayer(self, playerInfo) {
  player = self.physics.add.image(playerInfo.x, playerInfo.y, 'player').setDisplaySize(200, 200);
  player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
}

function addOtherPlayers(self, playerInfo) {
  const otherPlayer = self.add.sprite(playerInfo.x, playerInfo.y, 'otherPlayer').setDisplaySize(200, 200);
    otherPlayer.playerId = playerInfo.playerId;
    otherPlayers[playerInfo.playerId] = otherPlayer;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps clarify what "trying to go back to the first of the second" means here.

Comment: I want to switch scenes freely. Load the first one when it collides with a trigger in the second scene, or load the first one when it collides with a trigger in the second scene. But after loading the second scene, in the event of a collision with a trigger, the player simply freezes and does not move.

Comment: Is `update` called? Have you tried setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code with the debugger?

Comment: FWIW It feels like `update() {` might be in one place with a `player` parameter and called and not two to make it more DRY.

Comment: @Kory check the browser console for an error. Phaser applications freeze when a error occurs

Comment: @Kory the freeze could also be cause through a endless loop since, the trigger is in the same place and the player is placed to a position, where a collision can occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well **I assume** the error happens because `player` is created/set in the `first` scene, and not more in the `second` scene, AND in the `update` function of the `second` sence you are accessing the `player` variable. *(**Or** it could be a endless loop do to same trigger position in both scences)*

The best solution would be to use a property for the player and not a global variable.  *like `this.player = ...`*. you would have to create the player in each scene and/or pass data, that has to be shared.

> **Info:** If a phaser *game/application* freezes, the best solution is to check the browser console for errors. Like this you can find the cause of the problem, pretty fast.

**Here a stripped down version of your code working, with the aforementioned correction *(minus the socket stuff)*:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

const TEMP_LOCATION =  { x: 20, y: 20 };

class FirstScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'first' });
  }

  init(data) {
    console.log('Updating FirstScene');
  }

  create() {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'SCENE 1');
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
   
    addPlayer(this, TEMP_LOCATION); 
    
    const trigger = this.add.rectangle(400, -12, 100, 100, 0xffffff).setDisplaySize(50, 50);
    // Define the collider after the player has been created
    this.physics.add.existing(trigger, true);
    
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, trigger, () => {
      this.scene.switch('second');   
    });
  }

  update() {
    if(this.player) {
      if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(-160);
      } else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(160);
      } else {
        this.player.setVelocityX(0);
      }
      if (this.cursors.up.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityY(-160);
      } else if (this.cursors.down.isDown) {
         this.player.setVelocityY(160);
      } else {
        this.player.setVelocityY(0);
      }
    }
  }
}

class SecondScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'second' });
  }

  create() {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'SCENE 2');
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    addPlayer(this, TEMP_LOCATION); // temp location

    const trigger = this.add.rectangle(400, -12, 100, 100, 0xffffff).setDisplaySize(50, 50);

    // Define the collider after the player has been created
    this.physics.add.existing(trigger, true);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, trigger, () => {
      this.scene.switch('first');
    });
  }

  update() {
    if(this.player) {
      if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(-160);
      } else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityX(160);
      } else {
        this.player.setVelocityX(0);
      }
      if (this.cursors.up.isDown) {
        this.player.setVelocityY(-160);
      } else if (this.cursors.down.isDown) {
         this.player.setVelocityY(160);
      } else {
        this.player.setVelocityY(0);
      }
    }
  }
}

const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 536,
  height: 183,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 0 }
    }
  },
  scene: [FirstScene, SecondScene]
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function addPlayer(self, playerInfo) {
  self.player = self.physics.add.image(playerInfo.x, playerInfo.y, 'player');
  self.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
}
```

```html
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> I would recommend creating a own Custom Scene, to inherit from to keep duplication could look like this:

**Some Code Cleanup:**

```js
class BaseScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor(key) {
        super({ key });
    }

    create() {
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        addPlayer(this, TEMP_LOCATION);
        // and other duplicate code
        // ...
    }

    update() {
        if (this.player) {
            if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityX(-160);
            } else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityX(160);
            } else {
                this.player.setVelocityX(0);
            }
            if (this.cursors.up.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityY(-160);
            } else if (this.cursors.down.isDown) {
                this.player.setVelocityY(160);
            } else {
                this.player.setVelocityY(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

class FirstScene extends BaseScene {
    constructor() {
        super('first');
    }

    create() {
        super.create();
        // other none duplicate code
        // ...
    }

    update() {
        super.update();
        // other none duplicate code
        // ...
    }
}

class SecondScene extends BaseScene {
    constructor() {
        super('second' );
    }

    create() {
        super.create();
        // other none duplicate code
        // ...
    }

    update() {
        super.update();
        // other none duplicate code
        // ...
    }
}
```